# Error while installing mongodb on opensuse

Tags: mongodb, openssl, opensuse

I have followed steps mentioned on mongodb site http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-suse

But i am getting an error while running `mongo` command in terminal.

`mongo: symbol lookup error: mongo: undefined symbol: FIPS_mode_set`

Also i am not able to run any service related to mongo, such as
`sudo service mongod start`

It is getting failed without any information.

Can any one help me understand what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is compatibility between the latest versions (in suse repository) of openssl and mongodb. You need to install these versions:

```
mongodb 3.0.4-1
openssl 1.0.1k-2.20.1
```

Comment: Did you manually installed `openssl 1.0.1k-2.20.1` or through zypper?

Comment: I have installed it using YAST - software management. Type "openssl" to searchbox, select libopenssl1_0_0 go to description area and click to Versions tab. Similarly if you have installed mongo db using install manual on mongodb.org you have additional repo with mongo and you can select mongo version same way.

Answer (score 1):

For openSuSE tumbleweed there is a workaround detailed here (it might work on other versions/distributions):

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-20259

```
zypper in libopenssl-devel
rpm -e --nodeps libopenssl0_9_8
cd /usr/lib64/
ln -s libssl.so libssl.so.0.9.8
ln -s libcrypto.so libcrypto.so.0.9.8
```

Comment: Still works (and seems to be the only way) on openSUSE Leap 42.1 as of June 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Releases of mongodb for all different openSUSE versions are in designated *server:database* repos. Full list can be found at http://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=server:database&package=mongodb

For openSUSE Tumbleweed

```
zypper addrepo http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/server:database/openSUSE_Tumbleweed/server:database.repo
zypper refresh
zypper install mongodb
```

openSUSE 13.2

```
zypper addrepo http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/server:database/openSUSE_13.2/server:database.repo
zypper refresh
zypper install mongodb
```